# Deactivate middle foldmark in scrlttr2

Tags: scrlttr2

I would like to remove the middle foldmark, just leaving the upper and lower: I think `m` should do it but it is not working for me.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, foldmarks=true, foldmarks=mBT]{scrlttr2}

\setkomavar{fromname}{my name}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{my house \\ my address}


\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{address}

\opening{Dear all,}

This is a letter. 

\closing{Yours faithfully,}

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of the MWE in the question:

[image]

Note, there is an misunderstanding: The longer tick that you see in the middle is not the middle foldmark. It is the punch or center mark and its symbols are `P` (to activate) and `p`(to deactivate). So you have to use `foldmarks=pBT`.

```
\documentclass[foldmarks=pBT]{scrlttr2}

\setkomavar{fromname}{my name}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{my house \\ my address}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{address}
\opening{Dear all,}
This is a letter. 
\closing{Yours faithfully,}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

results in

[image]

---

The additional middle foldmark is not required in European letters. Therefore this foldmark is decatived by the `DIN.lco` which is loaded by `scrlttr2` automatically. Inside the `DIN.lco` is set to zero. So there will be no middle foldmark even if you use `foldmark=M`.

Comment: Ah, that explains it! It was me misunderstanding terminology. Many thanks,